# Django: Can I redirect an unauthenticated user which hits /admin/

Tags: python, django, redirect, authentication

I have a custom Authentication system in a django app I'm working on.

I've set the LOGIN_URL in the settings, and the auth system is working great.

I'd like to be able to redirect an unauthenticated user when they hit /admin/ to the main auth system instead of the django.contrib.auth model rendering its own login form.
I'd also like that the /admin/logout page would do something similar

The django.contrib.auth model is just used for the User and Group models. The LOGIN_URL is now set to /saml2/login/ I'd like to make so that unauthenticated requests to /admin/ are sent to this LOGIN_URL

What's the cleanest way to get this done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Authentication (Custom Login Page)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428336/django-authentication-custom-login-page)

Comment: You say you have a custom authentication system, but you are still using `django.contrib.auth` model's login form. Can you update the question with the setting for `LOGIN_URL` and the view that it is pointing to?

Comment: updated with the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a suitable solution:

[How can I not use Django's admin login view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779265/how-can-i-not-use-djangos-admin-login-view)

Its basically wrapping the admin view in a login_required view.

Comment: i use the decorator @login_required(login_url='/login/') where /login/ is an url i setup like this in urls.py                        url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),

Comment: That won't redirect when a user goes to /admin/

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom Login View and set your LOGIN_URL to point to this view.
this may help : [Django Authentication (Custom Login Page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428336/django-authentication-custom-login-page)